# lag in apply statement doesn't work in R

Tags: r, time-series, apply, lag

I'm trying to "apply" a function that does "lag"s on zoo objects in R.

The function works correctly if I pass a single zoo vector - it applys the lag and everything works.

However, if I `apply( data, 1, function )` then the lag doesn't work.  There is no error, just the equivalent of a zero lag.

This is also the case with a simple `apply( data, 1, lag )`.

Can anyone explain why this should be the case?  Is there anything I can do to make the lag to occur?

Comment: Is lag(data) do what you want? If not please extend you question (sample data, expected output)

Answer (score 3):

Here's some data:

```
 > x <- zoo(matrix(1:12, 4, 3), as.Date("2003-01-01") + 0:3)
 > x
 2003-01-01 1 5  9
 2003-01-02 2 6 10
 2003-01-03 3 7 11
 2003-01-04 4 8 12
```

If you want to lag this multivariate time series, just call lag (i.e. no need for apply):

```
 > lag(x)                 
 2003-01-01 2 6 10
 2003-01-02 3 7 11
 2003-01-03 4 8 12
```

If you want to apply a function across the rows, it needs to be sensible.  For instance, to get mean of the row values:

```
> apply(x, 1, mean)
2003-01-01 2003-01-02 2003-01-03 2003-01-04 
         5          6          7          8
```

You can't apply a zoo object and get a zoo object back.  The output of apply is "a vector or array or list of values".  In the example above:

```
> class(apply(x, 1, mean))
[1] "numeric"
```

You need to recreate it as a zoo object and then lag it:

```
> lag(zoo(apply(coredata(x), 1, mean), index(x)))
 2003-01-01 2003-01-02 2003-01-03 
         6          7          8
```

You need to be slightly careful of the direction of your output.  But you can transpose it if necessary with the `t()` function.  For instance:

```
> zoo(t(apply(coredata(x), 1, quantile)), index(x))
           0% 25% 50% 75% 100%
2003-01-01  1   3   5   7    9
2003-01-02  2   4   6   8   10
2003-01-03  3   5   7   9   11
2003-01-04  4   6   8  10   12
```

You could also wrap this in a function.  Alternatively you can use one of the apply functions in the `xts` time series library (this will retain the time series object in the process):

```
> x <- as.xts(x)
> apply.daily(x, mean)
           [,1]
2003-01-01    5
2003-01-02    6
2003-01-03    7
2003-01-04    8
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try `quantmod::Lag` function for generating a matrix consisting of various lagged-series of a series, at different lag values? For example

```
> quantmod::Lag (1:10, k=c(0,5,2))
```

will return

> ```
> Lag.0 Lag.5 Lag.2
>  [1,]     1    NA    NA
>  [2,]     2    NA    NA
>  [3,]     3    NA     1
>  [4,]     4    NA     2
>  [5,]     5    NA     3
>  [6,]     6     1     4
>  [7,]     7     2     5
>  [8,]     8     3     6
>  [9,]     9     4     7
> [10,]    10     5     8
> ```

Answer (score 0):

@Marek - lag(data) does do what I want, but I wanted to be able to use this as part of an "apply" construct to make the vector->matrix abstraction a little easier.

Comment: Just based on everything here, I think you might benefit from more time understanding `zoo` objects, and particularly how they're different from vectors.  Have you read the vignette: vignette("zoo")?